# react issue when setting video tags srcObject

Tags: html, reactjs, video-streaming, html5-video

What I'm trying to do is set the video's src to my laptop's camera. This way but I'm getting this weird error. even though I'm getting this error the code works fine. I'm not able to find much information on this. I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction or being helped with a solution.

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for video. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
in video (at App.jsx:34)
in div (at App.jsx:33)
in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

Bellow, you will find my App.jsx file.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        start: false,
        stream: false
    }
    setOutGoingVideoStream = (node) => {
        this.setOutGoingVideoStream = node
    }
    start = (e) => {    
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: true,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
            console.log("Starting stream")
            this.setOutGoingVideoStream.srcObject = stream;
            this.setState({start: true, stream})
        })
        .catch(e => alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`));
    }
    hangup = () => {
      console.log('Ending call');
      this.state.stream.getTracks()[0].stop();
      this.state.stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      this.setState({start: false, stream: false})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <video
                    ref={this.setOutGoingVideoStream}
                    playsInline
                    autoPlay
                    muted
                />
                <button
                    onClick = {this.start}
                    disabled = {this.state.start}
                >
                    request permission
                </button>
                <button

                >
                    call
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={this.hangup}
                    disabled={!this.state.start}
                >
                    hang up
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @4pie0 I did not